# HTML5 enabling scripts

Tags: html

I am keen to try out one of the HTML5 js plugins to use HTML5 markup on a new client project. Has anybody had experience using Remy Sharp's HTML5 enabler (http://remysharp.com/2009/01/07/html5-enabling-script/) or the Modernizr plugin (http://www.modernizr.com/) on a project that can offer tips or gotchas? I am supporting IE7+ as well as the modern browsers.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remy's script is pretty solid. And the latest version has Jon Neal's print enabler plugin as well so you should be good.

Comment: Modernizr includes the entire html5shim which includes the ie print protector. So it's all kinda the same solution for the same problem. :)